# Python regex for everything up to a blank line

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a way regex that will get me everything in a piece of text up to the first blank line. I have the following:

```
reg = r'((Opposition|Oppose):?\s*)(.*?)\n\n'
str1 = """Opposition


          California Attorneys for Criminal Justice
          Californians for Safety and Justice
          Drug Policy Alliance
          Friends Committee on Legislation of California
          Legal Services for Prisoners with Children


           Analysis Prepared  
"""

str2 = """Oppose:   None received

                                      -- END --

                                      """
```

When I run:

```
match  = re.search(reg, str1, re.DOTALL)
print ma
tch.group(3)
```

I get:

```
      California Attorneys for Criminal Justice
      Californians for Safety and Justice
      Drug Policy Alliance
      Friends Committee on Legislation of California
      Legal Services for Prisoners with Children
```

But when I run:

```
match = re.search(reg, str2, re.DOTALL)
print match.group(3)
```

I get:

```
   None received
                                      -- END --
```

The the outcome for the first string is correct, but what I want from the second string is just the "None received". I can't come up with a good explanation for why I get the "-- END --" as well. Shouldn't my regex match the \n after "None received" as well as the \n on the blank line and stop? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any white space on the blank line?

Comment: Oh, it was the tab characters on the newline that got me. Thanks 'stribizhev' for the regex, that worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure you match whitespace-only lines with `[^\S\n]*` (= *match 0 or more characters other than non-whitespace or newlines*):

```
((Oppos(?:e|ition)):?\s*)(.*?)\n[^\S\n]*\n[^\S\n]*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xD4dE0/1)

I also shortened the 2nd capture group a bit.

Here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/a9IHWU)